# Количество заданий в пересекающихся временных диапазонах

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица:

- sr.number - номер задания
- sr.open - дата создания задания
- sr.log_open - дата, когда сотрудник начал выполнение задания
- sr.log_close - дата, когда сотрудник закончил работу над заданием
- sr.login - логин сотрудника

Необходимо написать запрос, в котором будет:
время работы над заданием в виде временных промежутков;
количество заданий, которые были обработаны в этом диапазоне.

Пробовал через конкатенацию, но получается, что диапазоны пересекаются.
Приведу пример моей попытки, чтобы было понятнее:

```
 select t1.time|| ' - ' || t1.time + 3 as time,
 count(t1.num)
        from(
        select sr.log_close-sr.log_open as time,
        sr.number as num
        from prod) t1
    group by time
```

Пример входных данных:

```
sr.number   sr.open         sr.log_open     sr.log_close    sr.login
1           31.03.20 09:00  31.03.20 09:10  31.03.20 09:18  e.valich    
2           01.04.20 10:00  31.03.20 10:10  31.03.20 10:16  e.valich    
3           02.04.20 11:00  31.03.20 11:10  31.03.20 11:12  e.valich    
4           02.04.20 12:00  31.03.20 12:15  31.03.20 12:16  e.valich
5           02.04.20 13:00  31.03.20 13:15  31.03.20 13:20  e.valich
```

Пример выходных данных:

[image: Пример выходных данных]

Comment: Было бы, конечно, неплохо, если бы базу данных привели и саму попытку

Comment: Какая-то странная у вас таблица - должен быть id, все-таки.

Comment: Добавте пожалуйста в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1100222/edit) пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат (как текст).

Comment: _в виде временных промежутков_ - что вы понимаете под этим? Что такое - `1 - 4`, или как вы  это значение получили из входных данных? Что за магическое число 3 в запросе?

Comment: Временные промежутки это время обработки  sr.log_close-sr.log_open; Всё из исходных данных. Сначала находим время обработки каждого запроса. Потом из этих данных делаем диапазоны.

Comment: Нужно узнать, сколько запросов обработано в диапазоне 1-4 минуты. Потом 5-8 минут.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE testtable(
    id INTEGER primary key auto_increment,
    number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    open DATE NOT NULL,
    close DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO testtable
(number, open, close)
VALUES
    (1, '2000-01-01', '2004-01-01'),
    (1, '2001-01-01', '2005-01-01'),
    (1, '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01'),
    (2, '2000-01-01', '2010-01-01'),
    (2, '2004-01-01', '2008-01-01');

SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.open, t1.close, COUNT(*)
FROM
    testtable as t1
JOIN
    testtable as t2
ON
    (t2.open between t1.open AND t1.close)
    AND
    (t2.close between t1.open AND t1.close)
    AND
    t1.id <> t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Если я правильно понял задачу(считать то, чей диапазон полностью находится в текущем диапазоне).
Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные диапазоны - нули. Можно, конечно, и их присобачить:

```
SELECT
    id, open, close, MAX(count) as count
FROM
(SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.open, t1.close, COUNT(*) as count
FROM
    testtable as t1
JOIN
    testtable as t2
ON
    (t2.open between t1.open AND t1.close)
    AND
    (t2.close between t1.open AND t1.close)
    AND
    t1.id <> t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id

UNION

SELECT
    id, open, close, 0 as count
FROM
    testtable as t2) as t
GROUP BY id;
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]